# Combination of specific key and any other key

Tags: autohotkey

I would like to turn <kbd>F15</kbd> into a macro key. Pressing another key while F15 is held should call a function that will read a `.ini` file for instructions.

I know that I can it this like this, but I'd rather not have the giant list:

```
DoMacro(key) { ... }

F15 & a::DoMacro('a')
F15 & b::DoMacro('b')
F15 & c::DoMacro('c')
.
.
.
```

I tried fiddling around with `Input`, but I couldn't figure out any way to capture (or even pass through) non-character keys. Is there any alternative to the long list?

Comment: Why do you need `Input` to consume non-character keys?

Comment: Because I would like to tie macros to other keys, such as the arrow keys.

Comment: It is pretty easy to catch those keys as well using: `Input, SingleKey, L1, {Left}{Right}{Up}{Down}` You can add any key to that list. For instance, if `F15` + `Down` is pressed, `ErrorLevel` will contain `EndKey:Down` (not sure if lower/upper case). You can check it out in the [docs](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/Input.htm).

Comment: You could also dynamically create them with the `Hotkey` command + "ASCII loop".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no 100% nice way to do this in AHK (unless you know a way to do it through API calls which I don't).
I think the best you could make out of this situation is this:

```
GetAnyKey(timeout) {
    Input, PressedKey, T%timeout% L1, {F1}{F2}{F3}{F4}{F5}{F6}{F7}{F8}{F9}{F10}{F11}{F12}{F14}{F15}{F16}{F17}{F18}{F19}{F20}{F21}{F22}{F23}{F24}{PrintScreen}{Del}{Home}{End}{PgUp}{PgDn}{ScrollLock}{Pause}{Ins}{BS}{Space}{Left}{Right}{Up}{Down}{Left}{Right}{NumLock}{NumPad1}{NumPad2}{NumPad3}{NumPad4}{NumPad5}{NumPad6}{NumPad7}{NumPad8}{NumPad9}{NumPad0}{NumPadAdd}{NumPadSub}{NumPadMult}{NumPadDiv}{NumPadEnter}{NumPadDot}{NumPadEnd}{NumPadHome}{NumPadPgDn}{NumPadPgUp}{NumpadClear}{NumpadDown}{NumpadIns}{NumpadLeft}{NumpadRight}{AppsKey}{LShift}{RShift}{LCtrl}{RCtrl}{LAlt}{RAlt}{LWin}{RWin}
    If (ErrorLevel = "Timeout")
        Return
    If PressedKey
        Key := PressedKey
    Else
        Key := SubStr(ErrorLevel,8)
    Return Key
}

F13::
    Key := GetAnyKey(1)
    If (Key && GetKeyState("F13", "P")) {
        DoMacro(Key)
    }
Return

DoMacro(Key) {
    MsgBox, F13 and %Key% have been pressed!
}
```

I removed the hotkey (F13) from the Input key list, so that it doesn't trigger the Input when you wait too long.
So, if you change the hotkey you have to change the input list accordingly.